# terminal top command different text colors

Tags: bash, terminal

on OSX, when I run top sometimes I see some different colors, namely black text....

What does it mean?
What bash setting do I need to change to make these a different color? black is too hard to read with my setup.

[image]

Comment: Not a programming question; voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that it was a simple text color in the terminal preferences, I think the title of the setting was 'bold text'